# How to make sure that logging out from iCloud deletes local data?

Tags: ios, icloud

When I sign out from icloud on my ios device - ipad or iphone, my local data is not removed. I am not keeping local data, I do want all locally stored data removed from the device when I logout from my icloud account.

This issue started from ios 12 and it is still present in ios 13. I asked question in apple support and they told me to do different things and none of them helped.

So which other options do I have to fix this?

Comment: What do you need help with: deleting local data after disabling iCloud, cleaning up 10k of duplicate photos or something else?

Comment: Hey! Addded an update in the description. I need the data to be deleted when I sign out, and not to delete it manually every time I sign out.

Comment: I’ve edited the question down to the actual issue. Can you maybe add the things Apple Support asked you to do so people here don‘t recommend the same steps again?